# Why is this bulk insert/load statement (SSMS) throwing a conversion error message?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert data from a group of `.csv` files, with the corresponding table for each having been created successfully. I have moved these files from a mac, so I specified the following in the insert:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[DimBeat]
FROM '$(SqlSamplesSourceDataPath)DimBeat.csv'
WITH (
    CHECK_CONSTRAINTS,
    --CODEPAGE='ACP',
    DATAFILETYPE='char',
    FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
    ROWTERMINATOR='0x0A',
    --KEEPIDENTITY,
    TABLOCK
);
```

The same 2 error messages are repeated identically for all the Dim tables. The following are the details for one csv that gives the error: 2 rows, with an increasing ID number from 1-300K, and a 3 digit code

```
CREATE TABLE DimBeat
(
    CrimeNumber bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    Beat varchar(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL
)
```

When I attempt to run the bulk insert, the following errors appear:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 95631, column 1 (CrimeNumber).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 191340, column 1 (CrimeNumber).

I have checked the [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJcTK.png) and [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F5Wt.png) visually in excel and by type in R, with no observable difference to the rest of the values in their respective columns other than their large size; however I believe they are still within the limits of bigint.

Would anyone have an idea as to why this error is occurring?

Comment: can you insert to temp table with dataType nvarchar?

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the rugby row numbers, not just the rows with the values?

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi in with both variables just being nvarchar and no primary key?

Comment: @SBFrancies, sent the wrong images, edited now thanks

Comment: It's probably trying to convert the scientific notation to an int which I don't think ssms can do.

Comment: So maybe format the file so it displays 10000, 10001, etc instead.

Comment: Yeah,create table twmpdimbeat(CrimeNumber nvarchar(max),Beat nvarchar (max)).maybe you can't insert to this table because can't convert or hasn't unique value of two column and etc.

Comment: If the OP needs 4,000 characters for their Crime Numbers, @abolfazlsadeghi , I'd be concerned by the crime levels in their area; that's a terrifyingly high number.

Comment: The error message references row 191340. Have you checked that row visually using Excel or a text editor?

Comment: @DanGuzman please see the attached images in the question for their appearance in excel, I also double-checked the types in R

Comment: @SBFrancies You were right, thanks! forcing R to write into the csv the full values solved those error messages, the only one left now is the "unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file" which may be more difficult

Comment: probably you need an extra newline at the end of file